# How we can add class like the below code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How we can add class like the below code

```
<ul>
<li class="one">one</li>
<li class="two">one</li>
<li class="three">one</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This isn't currently a question. Explain what exactly you are trying to do (give specific input and expected output) and explain what you have tried so far. Also, read the documentation. http://api.jquery.com/addClass. It is probably a good idea to see the [StackOverflow FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) on asking questions.

Comment: Place your hands on the keyboard, search for relevant keys, start typing by pressing each of them in desired order.

Comment: @BackinaFlash : good one....lol....

Answer (score 3):

**JS**

```
$("li").each(function(i) {
    $(this).addClass("0" + (i+1));
});
```

**CSS**

```
ul.class{margin:0;padding:0;}
ul.class li{
    margin:0.3em;
}
ul.class li:nth-child(1){
    background-color:#fff;
}
ul.class li:nth-child(2){
    background-color:#ccc;
}
ul.class li:nth-child(3){
    background-color:#666;
}
ul.class li:nth-child(4){
    background-color:#999;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong, I think it can be this:

```
$("li").each(function(idx){
     $(this).addClass(idx));
});
```

Comment: You do realize the index is going to be an integer, right...zero-based, in fact...